# Set width and background for cell in excel using spreadsheet rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I used the following code

```
title_format = Spreadsheet::Format.new(:color => :blue, :pattern_fg_color => :red, :weight => :bold, :size => 18)
sheet1.row(0).set_format(0, title_format)
```

Font color is working but I am unable to get background color and also i need to increase the width of the cell. How can i do.

**Edit 1**

I changed like this

```
bg_color = Spreadsheet::Format.new({
    :weight => :bold,
    :pattern_fg_color => :red,
    :size => 8
    })

[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11].each{
    |col|
    sheet1.row(0).set_format(col,bg_color) 
}
```

What mistake i did in this. It is not wokring

**Edit 2**

This solves and working

```
bg_color = Spreadsheet::Format.new({
        :weight => :bold,
        :patterb_fg_color => :red,
        :size => 8
        })

sheet1.row(0).default_format = bg_color
```

Comment: Do you create a new document or update an existing one?

Comment: using existing one only

Comment: i experienced same problems with updating the document. Cell formats didn't apply to cells. The only thing I сame up with is to generate document from scratch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set background color through:

```
title_format = Spreadsheet::Format.new({
  :weight           => :bold,
  :pattern_bg_color => :grey,
  :size             => 8
})

sheet.row(0).set_format(column_index, title_format)
```

The width of the cell you can set like this:

```
sheet1.column(column_index).width = 1 # but i don't really know in what units it is measured
```

Comment: How do i set same width for multiple column

Comment: What does `column_index` implies

Comment: There is no way to set same width for multiple columns in one line. In the loop, for example. `[1,2,5,7].each{|col| sheet1.column(col).width = 1}`

Comment: column_index 0 is the column A in excel

Comment: Thats working good. How do i set background color for header column alone

Comment: I tried something like this `sheet1.row(0).column(col).pattern_bg_color = 'black'` but not working

Comment: now i need to set alternate color for rows how can i do it in loop